# Spring Social: redirect url when server behind proxy

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

In my Spring Boot app I have implemented login using Spring Social (1.1.4.RELEASE) (Facebook, Google, LinkedIn and Twitter).

During the login process the server calls the following HTTP GET:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://xzy.com:91/auth/google&scope=email&state=YYY
```

Problem is here: **redirect_uri=http://xzy.com:91/auth/google**

The app in behind the proxy and I need to **change the redirect_uri** to

**http://xzy.com:91/auth/google -> http://xzy.com/auth/google**

I guess this is pretty common problem, but I wasn't able to find working solution (

my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-linkedin.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-twitter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-google.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-facebook.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Bean
public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
    ProviderSignInController controller = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new SimpleSignInAdapter());
    // get the url from config, this just for example
    controller.setApplicationUrl("http://xzy.com");
    return controller;
}
```

As you can read from the code in `spring-social`, the `application url` will replace the base url.

```
protected String callbackUrl(NativeWebRequest request) {
        if (callbackUrl != null) {
            return callbackUrl;
        }
        HttpServletRequest nativeRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        if (applicationUrl != null) {
            return applicationUrl + connectPath(nativeRequest);
        } else {
            return nativeRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still doesn't work. It seems that this will work for HTTP GET xxx/signup/facebook, but my request is xxx/auth/facebook

Comment: Please post you config

Comment: Can this be done dynamically to? In my case I have a website on e.g. `localhost:4200` that I want to redirect to after the user signed up. But what if I had a second client on `localhost:4201`? Is it possible to change that behavior based on who is calling?

Comment: Did you find solution for this? @TomasMarik